# How do I make this bidirectional switch work with inductive and capacitive loads?

Tags: switches, bidirectional

I designed the bidirectional switch seen below. But right after, I realized that it would only work with resistive loads. However I want this to be a general purpose product, which will also control capacitive and inductive loads (e.g.; an electric motor).

What kind of changes should I make on it?

[image]

Typical application:
[image]

Comment: What is GND_ISO, and are you absolutely certain it's safe to connect live AC to it via those body diodes?

Comment: @BrianDrummond xxx_ISO grids are isolated voltage sources. What is wrong with the body diodes? Aren't they connected back to back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be done in the control unfortunately

Bidirection switches like that are used for Matrix converters all the time (will IGBT mind...)

The two golden rules:

- **THOU SHALL NOT OPEN-CIRCUIT THE LOAD**
- **THOU SHALL NOT SHORT-CIRCUIT THE SUPPLY**

which results in very good monitoring to ensure correct commutation. Equally such bidirectional switches take in essencially 3 commands

1. SWT A on
2. SWT B on
3. BOTH switches OFF

At the moment, your topology only provides #3 and a hybrid of #1 and #2

Comment: Do you mean, 1) I need a more sophisticated control circuit, 2) I have to drive the MOSFETs independently?

Comment: #1:  Yes unfortunately, you need to know what the current is doing so you don't try to open a charged inductor. #2 you might not have to, that is application specific. I have done matrix converters before and the control law indicate all 3 states. Depending on the type of load you might not need the 3 specific states to be controllable